Find the intervals of increase and decrease of the function $f(x)=x-2 \sin x$.
The problem:
Find the intervals of increase and decrease of the function $f(x)=x-2 \sin x$.
What I have tried:
$$f'(x)=0 \implies 1-2\cos{x}=0 \iff 2\cos{x}=1 \iff \cos{x}=\frac{1}{2} \iff x=\frac{\pi}{3}$$
My question:
No solution is provided for this problem so I do not know what conclusion I am to reach. What is the conclusion? On a previous problem similar to this one it was pretty obvious where the function was increasing and decreasing, but with this one I am not getting it.

Perhaps when $x \lt \frac{\pi}{3}$ the function is decreasing and when $x \gt \frac{\pi}{3}$ it's increasing?

Set $f'(x)>0$ for increasing and $f'(x)<0$ for decreasing. You can search up how to solve trigonometric inequalities.

So, decreasing on $x\lt \frac{\pi}{3}$ and increasing on $x\gt \frac{\pi}{3}$ is correct?

No, consider what happens when $x=2\pi$ for example.

Try sketching the function $f'(x)$. You'll see why your logic is wrong.

Could you please explain how I figure out where the function is increasing and decreasing?

I suggest you to first consider $x \mod 2\pi$. Then graph $f'(x)$ in $[0,2\pi)$. Check where $f'(x)$ is positive, negative, etc. Your final answer will rely on an arbitrary integer multiple of $2\pi$.

As you correctly computed, the first derivative of your function $f(x)$ is
$$f'(x)=1-2\cos x$$
The zeros of $f'(x)$ are
\begin{align}
f'(x)=0\:&\Longleftrightarrow\:1-2\cos x=0
\\&\Longleftrightarrow\:\cos x=\frac12
\\&\Longleftrightarrow\:x=\frac\pi3+2k\pi\:\wedge\:x=\frac53\pi+2k\pi,\qquad k\in\mathbb Z
\end{align}
Let's fix $k\in\mathbb Z$ and let's observe that if $x\in\left(\frac\pi3+2k\pi,\frac53\pi+2k\pi\right)$ then $\cos x<\frac12$, so $-2\cos x>-1$ and in particular
$$f'(x)=1-2\cos x>0 $$
While if $x\in\left(\frac53\pi+2k\pi,\frac\pi3+2(k+1)\pi\right)$ then $\cos x>\frac12$, so $-2\cos x<-1$ and in particular
$$f'(x)=1-2\cos x<0$$
Ultimately the function $f$ is increasing on all the intervals of the form $\left(\frac\pi3+2k\pi,\frac53\pi+2k\pi\right)$ and decreasing on the intervals on all the intervals of the form $\left(\frac53\pi+2k\pi,\frac\pi3+2(k+1)\pi\right)$, with $k$ varying in $\mathbb Z$.

Everything seems clear to me in this solution up until I arrive to $x\in\left(\frac53\pi+2k\pi,\frac\pi3+2(k+1)\pi\right)$. Why is there a $(k+1)$?

Perhaps because it includes the next orbit around the unit circle?

@Sien Yes, exactly because it includes the next orbit around the unit circle.


From what you have tried, you have only found one stationary point of $f$.

Firstly, note that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are oscillating functions, hence the hint of the question to find "intervals". So this means there is more than the one stationary point.
As a matter of fact $\cos{x} = 1/2$ has solutions in quadrants $1$ and $4$ of the unit circle and angles are dimensionless so there are infinite solutions/stationary points. Hence, we express them in general form:
with base angles $x = \pi/3$ and $x = 5\pi/3$, and $\cos{x}$ being periodic over $2\pi$ so your solution becomes $x = 2k\pi \pm \pi/3, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
However, this is only a piece of the puzzle. We have found the points where $f$ is neither increasing or decreasing, or precisely the intervals that you require. Are you able to solve which intervals are increasing or decreasing?

Hint: Since the $f'$ is periodic indefinitely, there will be a pattern in which intervals increase or decrease.


Could it be that the function is decreasing when $k$ in $x = 2k\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$ is negative?

@Sien Not quite. See as mentioned that $x = 2k\pi \pm \pi/3$ are the stationary points (points where the function does not increase or decrease). So your look for values in between these points, which in turn form your intervals.
